# Get-RDUsersession is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I have problems running a script with Powershell in Windows 7.

The script just retrieves a list of all connected user in terminal server in order to connect to them via "mstsc.exe". The problem is that when I run `cmdlet "Get-RDUsersession"` it returns that it is not recognized as the name of a `cmdlet`.

I already knew that it could be an error because before running this `cmdlet`, I had to install the RSAT administrative tools for windows in order to have all of the modules dedicated to "remotedesktop" and "active directory".

In fact, I've done both Windows 7 and Windows 10, but in Windows 10 it works just fine, while Windows 7 that error came up.

Moreover, I saw that in the path `C:\Windows\system32\WindowPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` there is no remote desktop module, while there is in Windows 10.

Is it normal? How can I run that `cmdlet` in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not had Win7 in my environment for years now, so, no way for me to sanitly check directly. However, if you are saying you downloaded and installed the Win7 version of RSAT (there are different installer for WinOS Clinet versions), and RSAT is not in any of the module paths, there are several module paths, then something went wrong with your RSAT install.

Also, of note, PowerShell cmdlets availability differs on WinClient versions, even if you have installed the latest builds. Some cmdlets are only available to the OS version that they were designed for.

If all else fails, you can use Implicit PS Remoting to a new machine and proxy the cmdlets from that machine and use them. In implicit sessions, the cmdlets are actually ran on the remote host, not your local station that you are using them from.

So, if you do the below on your WIn7 and Win10 systems, what are the results?

```
Get-Command -Name Get-RDUsersession

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Get-RDUserSession                                  2.0.0.0    RemoteDesktop



 Get-Module -Name RemoteDesktop

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   2.0.0.0    RemoteDesktop                       {Add-RDServer, Add-RDSessionHost,...


Import-Module -Name RemoteDesktop -Verbose
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried the commands you've writed and the result on Windows 10 is the same as yours while on W7 the result is:

Get-Command : The term 'Get-RDUsersession' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operabl
e program. 

PS H:\> Get-Module -name RemoteDesktop 

PS H:\> Import-Module -name RemoteDesktop -Verbose
Import-Module : The specified module 'RemoteDesktop' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any modul
e directory.

The strange thing is that it seemed that "Get-Module -name RemoteDesktop" it worked.

Comment: Yep, then RSAT is not on the box, run the WIn7 RSAT installer again to see if the corrects things for you. If not, use the implicit PSRemoting approach to a Win8+ or Server that has RSAT installed/enabled to do what you need. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/09/08/remoting-the-implicit-way

Comment: Well i've tried to run again the Win7 RSAT but it didn't work. 
I'm gonna try now to use the implicit PSRemoting. Thank you  very much for your help.